# ASP.NET Core - Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x8007023e'

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm currently encountering a problem when I deploy my ASP.NET Core program on IIS, and I have no idea how to fix it. Could somebody tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Whether your application works well on IIS express or not? What version of Asp.net core version are you using, please make sure you install the same version of Asp.net Core at local and server side? Besides, try to collect the Application Event Log, and check the detailed error message, more detail information, you could refer [Troubleshoot on IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#troubleshoot-on-iis) and [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Probably missing some server roles or features.

Checking the Application Event Log I found the error '0x8007023e'
[image: AspNetCore Module V2]

Checking the System Event Log I found a WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) communication error:
[image: WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) communication error]

Then I installed the following roles and features:
[image: Roles and Features, WAS]

[image]

Also I reinstalled ASP.NET Core Module

Finally I had to reassign the app pool to the site, and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the application had been assigned to a different app pool, somehow. Changing it back fixed the issue.

IIS > {Application} > Advanced Settings > General > Application Pool